# Using SQL to calculate active customer base grouped by another category

Tags: sql, group-by

Using SQL (Snowflake), I would like to get an overview of our customer base per market segment per day.

The dataset I have is a set of all the energy contracts belonging to a fictitious energy company and looks like this:

| contract_start_date | contract_end_date | market_segment | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-08-04 | 2018-08-04 | Electricity | 300f835e0 |
| 2017-08-04 | 2018-08-04 | Gas | 300f835e0 |
| 2018-08-04 | 2018-12-04 | Electricity | 300f835e0 |
| 2018-01-01 | 2019-01-01 | Electricity | 129d716i8 |
| 2018-01-01 | 2019-01-01 | Gas | 129d716i8 |
| 2018-01-04 | 2019-01-04 | Electricity | 617f424i7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

On any given date, each customer can have only electricity, only gas, or both electricity and gas. My goal is to get an overview of our total active customer base per day, based on the different combinations of market_segment that are possible. So, for each date, I wish to end up with one column for those customers that only have an active gas contract on this date, one column for those customers that only have an active electricity contract on this date, and one column for those customers that have both an active electricity contract and an active gas contract on this date. Something like this:

| date_day | only_gas | only_elec | combo_elec_gas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-08-04 | 63 | 213 | 182 |
| 2017-08-05 | 63 | 213 | 189 |
| 2018-08-06 | 63 | 213 | 189 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I would think I would first need to use a CTE grouping by market_segment and then create a table using count() and grouping by date_day, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: If a customer has more than one contract, will all their contracts start and end on the same day?

Comment: No, not necessarily. They could end one of their contracts earlier than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you somewhere close to what you want:

```
-- Generate a list of all the dates in the required range
WITH DATE_LIST AS (
    select 
        dateadd(day, '+' || seq4(), '2017-08-01') as dte 
    from 
        table 
           (generator(rowcount => 550))
),
-- Create a list of all customers and their contracts on every date in the list
RAW_DATA (DTE, CUSTOMER_ID, MARKET_SEGMENT) AS (
    SELECT 
    DL.DTE
    ,CC.CUSTOMER_ID
    ,CC.MARKET_SEGMENT
    --,COUNT(CC.CUSTOMER_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY DL.DTE, CC.CUSTOMER_ID) CUST_COUNT
    --,COUNT(CC.CUSTOMER_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY DL.DTE, CC.CUSTOMER_ID, CC.MARKET_SEGMENT) CUST_SEG_COUNT
    FROM DATE_LIST DL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER_CONTRACTS CC ON DL.DTE BETWEEN CC.CONTRACT_START_DATE AND CC.CONTRACT_END_DATE
),
--Pivot the data to get electricity and gas counts into the same record for each customer/date
PIV_DATA AS (
    SELECT 
    P.*
    FROM RAW_DATA RD
    PIVOT (COUNT(MARKET_SEGMENT) FOR MARKET_SEGMENT IN ('Gas','Electricity')) 
    AS P (DTE, CUSTOMER_ID, GAS, ELECTRICITY)
)
SELECT
DTE
,SUM(CASE WHEN GAS = 1 AND ELECTRICITY = 1 then 1 else 0 end) combo_elec_gas
,SUM(CASE WHEN GAS = 1 AND ELECTRICITY = 0 then 1 else 0 end) only_gas
,SUM(CASE WHEN GAS = 0 AND ELECTRICITY = 1 then 1 else 0 end) only_elec
FROM PIV_DATA
group by dte
```